# integration phpbb and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, integration, phpbb3

After the integration of phpbb and wordpress with wp-united in the user profile can not change anything (eg to set the avatar). How to fix this problem? Also, after installing wp-united in phpbb does not appear in the admin panel menu tab wp-united

Answer (score -1):

wp-united never made it to an actual release/production state. You should not be using it in a live environment because its going to have problems like this. From what I can tell its been abandoned, at least on phpBB.com